# How to get Perl to match \r in files with windows EOL characters

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a perl script to identify files with Windows EOL characters, but `\r` matching doesn't seem to work.

Here's my test script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Slurp;

$winfile = read_file('windows-newlines.txt');
if($winfile =~ m/\r/) {
  print "winfile has windows newlines!\n"; # I expect to get here
}
else {
  print "winfile has unix newlines!\n"; # But I actually get here
}

$unixfile = read_file('unix-newlines.txt');
if($unixfile =~ m/\r/) {
  print "unixfile has windows newlines!\n";
}
else {
  print "unixfile has unix newlines!\n";
}
```

Here's what it outputs:

```
winfile has unix newlines!
unixfile has unix newlines!
```

I'm running this on Windows, and I can confirm in Notepad++ that the files definitely have the correct EOL characters:

[image: Screenshot of windows-newlines.txt in Notepad++]
[image: Screenshot of unix-newlines.txt in Notepad++]

Comment: Works for me (trying on Linux). Can you include the files?

Comment: @Robert accepted answer below resolved it. apparently only a problem running on windows

Comment: You should always use `use strict; use warnings`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless `binmode` is true (which is not in your code) `read_file` will change `\r\n` to `\n` on Windows. From [the code](https://metacpan.org/release/CAPOEIRAB/File-Slurp-9999.32/source/lib/File/Slurp.pm#L121):

```
# line endings if we're on Windows
${$buf_ref} =~ s/\015\012/\012/g if ${$buf_ref} && $is_win32 && !$opts->{binmode};
```

In order to keep the original encoding set binmode, like shown [in the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp#read_file):

```
my $bin = read_file('/path/file', { binmode => ':raw' });
```